# How to horizontally align v-combobox with text inside v-col in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm trying to figure out how to horizontally align two `v-col`, one of this columns has a `v-combobox`:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-container class="indigo lighten-5">
     <v-row no-gutters>
      <v-col cols="2">{{ o.id }} </v-col>
      <v-col cols="10">
        <v-combobox v-model="o.selected" :items="values" dense  class="ml-auto"></v-combobox>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Here there's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/alessmar/pen/yLJrxJJ)

How can I align those two columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [`align`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-row/#align) prop to the row component with `center` as value :

```
<v-row no-gutters align="center">
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to do that, you can add `class="d-flex align-center"` to the `v-row`

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-container class="indigo lighten-5">
     <v-row no-gutters class="d-flex align-center">
      <v-col cols="2">{{ o.id }} </v-col>
      <v-col cols="10">
        <v-combobox v-model="o.selected" :items="values" dense  class="ml-auto"></v-combobox>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/endlichfelipe/pen/VwjNGqN)